# Use APIs for sorting or algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, api, data-structures

In a programming language like Python Which will have better efficiency? if i use a sorting algorithm like merge sort to sort an array or If I use a built in API like sort() to sort the array? If Algorithms are independent of programming languages, then what is the advantage of algorithms over built in methods or API's

Comment: “API or algorithm” is a nonsensical question, they are not alternatives. An API is a public-facing interface for a library. An algorithm is a step-by-step description of a solution to a problem. Libraries use APIs and algorithms. `sort` implements a sort algorithm (called “timsort”) and provides an API which is used to call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why to use public APIs:

- The built in methods were written and reviewed by very experienced and many coders, and a lot of effort was invested to optimize them to be as efficient as it gets.
- Since the built in methods are public APIs, it is also means they are constantly used, which means you get a massive "free" testing. You are much more likely to detect issues in public APIs than in private ones, and once something is discovered - it will be fixed for you.
- Don't reinvent the wheel. Someone already programmed it for you, use it. If your profiler says there is a problem, think about replacing it. Not before.

Why to use custom made methods:

- That said, the public APIs are general case. If you need something
  very specific for your scenario, you might find a solution that will
  be more efficient, but it will take you quite some time to actually
  achieve better than the already optimize general purpose public API.

tl;dr: Use public APIs unless you:

1. Need it and can afford a lot of time to replace it.
2. Know what you are doing pretty well.
3. Intend to maintain it and do robust testing for it.

Comment: That means If I am asked to sort an array in some competitive programming  I can prefer APIs over algorithms?

Comment: @Manel that depends on the rules of the competition. If the *purpose* of the competition is to implement the algorithm, then you probably shouldn't use the builtin methods. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The libraries normally use well tested and correctly optimized algorythms. For example Python uses [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) which:

- is a stable sort (order of elements that compare equal is preserved)
- in the worst case takes O( n log ⁡ n ) comparisons to sort an array of n elements
- in the best case (when the input is already sorted) runs in linear time

Unless you have special requirements that make you know that for your particular data sets one sort algorythm will give best result you can use the standard library implementation.

The other reason to build a sort by hand, is evidently for academic purposes...